# Can tex engines have options depending on the distribution?

Tags: miktex, texlive

I mostly work on linux with texlive,
but sometimes with miktex in windows.
Now I even want to write some cross platform software based on latex.

By accident I found out that the option `-shell-escape` common to all tex engines in texlive does not exist in miktex.
There it is called `-enable-write18`....
Is this true? If so it is a superfluous and harmful difference.

Are there further differences known??

Comment: Texlive also works on windows. If you use the same distribution on all systems, you won't run into such problems.

Comment: You can certainly use `--shell-escape` as an option with miktex

Answer (score 1):

The commandline and its options have always been implementation specific.  looking at [miktex documentation](https://docs.miktex.org/manual/miktex-pdftex.html) there are several options I do not recognise from texlive,

`--aux-directory`, `--disable-installer`, `--enable-etex` etc.

Some, correspond to similar options in texlive's pdftex such as `--etex` some correspond to specific miktex features such as its package installer.

Comment: very intestesting link..
Is there an according documentation for texlive? 
I found https://www.tug.org/texlive/doc/texlive-en/texlive-en.html but this has a completely different focus. 
Are there further distributions?

Comment: just type  tex --help @user2609605